# Efficient way to convert a 2D bitmap into a 3D cube model?

Tags: c++, c, opengl, graphics, 3d

I want to create cube model of a 32x32 bitmap in opengl. For example, the result should look something like this given a 2D bitmap of Bob-omb from Super Mario: http://fc02.deviantart.net/fs49/f/2009/186/f/a/Bob_omb_in_Minecraft_by_Luafox.png The idea is to represent each 2D pixel from the bitmap as a 3D cube.

Each model will represent an enemy in a game so I need to be able to render these quickly.  What would be a good way of doing this?

One attempt I've made is to generate a static 3D model from the bitmap by first creating a 32x32x2 grid of vertices and then creating triangles from these vertices in the appropriate places to form the cube faces. One big problem I'm having though is how to store the colors and normals for the faces. The triangles of each face need to share a vertex and that shared vertex needs to store the color and the normal for that face. However, I don't think I have enough vertices for each face to have the appropriate color and normal. I can't think of an elegant way to solve this.

Comment: It's for a game. I want enemies that look like this.

Comment: are you shure you are asking the right question? in the end you already told how you did it, and then asked a different question.

Comment: You could loop through the non transparent pixels row by row and for each pixel push 4 verts to your array if there are no verts already at that position.In a similar manner you could insert 4 verts per pixel and after inserting all the verts, remove duplicates. Another way would be to keep track of existing pixels above the current row and only insert verts when they're new. This should give you these front verts, you can clone and offset them on Z to get the back faces, then loop through the 'edge' verts to 'sew' the faces for top,bottom,left,right. Check this out: http://bit.ly/fQuB5H

Comment: I did Conway's Game of Life in exactly this way... see photo: http://www.smoothjazzy.com/image_display.html?img=screensaver/scr_2.jpg  - if you really want me to, I can dig up the code for that, it's all OpenGL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding storing colors and normals for the faces; I think you have to accept that you need to duplicate vertices in the same position for the different faces.  If two vertices share some attributes but differ in others, they are essentially different - even if one attribute that they share is their position.

So, you should build some VBOs, with duplicate vertices as necessary.  You may want to run this as a design-time step and save the results into a convenient format to save some work at runtime.

**edit:** That doesn't mean that you need to have separate vertices for every single corner of every face of every cube.  Actually, the cheapest way to render what you want (while the blocks are together) with a reasonably easy implementation would probably be to render the front and back each as two triangles, using a texture for colour, `GL_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST` sampling and careful alignment of texture coordinates, using a pixel shader to clip on transparent texels.

You will then need to do a bit more work (not necessarily at run time) to work out which faces will be visible from the sides, and make each of those as geometry (all of that geometry being a single static VBO to display, thus reducing both the number of draw calls and geometry cost as compared to for example calling a -deprecated, although still often useful- display list for each cube).  Again, with care you can ensure that this precisely joins with the invisible parts of the front and back faces.

If you do then want to have your enemies blow up and have the constituent cubes go their separate ways, you can then switch to a more expensive version displaying every single cube.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I learnt this the hard way... By the way, I'm writing this for iPhone using OpenGL ES. Are there any guidelines about how many vertices is too many? I know this is a very general question, but if I want my game enemies to be, for example, based on 32x32 pixel bitmaps and I use 8 vertices to represent each pixel as a cube, that's 8192 vertices and a few thousand triangles. That sounds like a lot to me. I'm just wondering if this sounds very inefficient.

Comment: I don't really know about the iPhone hardware, but that doesn't sound like all that many verts to me.

Comment: Also, as long as you don't want to separate your cubes but just render similarly to the image you linked to, you need far fewer vertices than that.  You can avoid the internal faces which are hidden and also share vertices which appear on the same face (particularly if you use a texture for colour, such that there is less unique information that needs to be specified by vertex attributes).

Comment: d'oh, I've just realised how similar my suggestion is to the already upvoted answer, and that you comment you've already tried it.

Answer (score 2):

You'll be fastest if you render the front face as a single texture mapped GL_QUAD, using alpha and GL_ALPHA_TEST for the 'transparent' parts.  You then make the boundary, i.e. the non front-facing squares, as one or more GL_QUAD_STRIPs.

If you are determined to draw the sprite as a series of actual cubes, for example if you want to blow up the sprite into separate cubes, or if you have very detailed textures on the small cube faces, then make a display list for one cube and call that display list repeatedly.

Comment: Quads are deprecated and you shouldn't use them anymore. Hardware only renders tris.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I actually tried this approach recently but the problem I had was you can see seams (i.e. little gaps) where the holes in the texture mapped quad and the boundary quad strip meet. I couldn't work out a solution to this. I have it working by rendering the front and back using lots of small triangles but this uses a lot more rendering power.

Comment: @Richard If the seams are large, double check your maths.  If they are small (1px or less) then you can work around it by also drawing the front faces of the border cubes and removing some pixels round the border of the bitmap used for the partly-transparent front quad.  Put the front quad very slightly in front of the cubes.  Saves you drawing the vast majority of front faces of cubes, which are interior cubes.

Comment: They may still be useful, but note that display lists are also now officially deprecated...

Answer (score 0):

Just a hint on how you can find some interesting readings about that: search for "voxel".
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voxel

Maybe you would like to take a look to the source code of the open source game engines Cube/Sauerbraten, that are based on cubes subdivision for the maps, and come with a nice in-game editor:
http://sauerbraten.org/